# c3.js with json ,split line line

Tags: c3.js

I have a JSON array and want to make a chart with C3.js. My example gives me only one line. I want to display however one line for every user. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
this.chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        json: [
            {
                ExamID: 'Exam1',
                result: 80,
                user:"user1"
            },
            {
                ExamID: 'Exam2',
                result: 90,
                user:"user1"
            },
            {
                ExamID: 'Exam1',
                result: 70,
                user:"user2"
            },
            {
                ExamID: 'Exam2',
                result: 60,
                user:"user2"
            }
        ],
        keys: {
            x: 'ExamID',
            value: ['result'],
        },
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a different JSON structure. Every object in the array (every exam) needs to have the results of all students in it. You can use a key for every student and rename the key for the legend with the attribute `names`. Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b5pd3wn6/

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#element",
    data: {
        json: [
            {
                ExamID: 'Exam1',
                user1: 80,
                user2: 50
            }, {
                ExamID: 'Exam2',
                user1: 90,
                user2: 40
            }
        ],
        keys: {
            x: 'ExamID',
            value: ['user1', 'user2']
        },
        names: {
            'user1': 'Peter Miller',
            'user2': 'Vladimir Peterhans'
        }
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i already accepted it , many many thanks again , and sorry for my poor English

Comment: sorry @ssc-hrep3  , if i test your solution with my example it gives me wrong chart
try to test this data 
            {
              ExamID: 'Exam1',
                result: 80,
                user:"user1"
            },
            {
                ExamID: 'Exam2',
                result: 90,
                user:"user1"
            },
            {
                ExamID: 'Exam1',
                result: 70,
                user:"user2"
            },
            {
                ExamID: 'Exam2',
                result: 60,
                user:"user2"
            }

Comment: You are using wrong input data. You need to have one object for each exam. This object then has multiple fields for every user. Please read the answer again and see how the data needs to be structured. You can also edit the JSFiddle to test it. And accepting an answer in StackOverflow is done with the green checkmark symbol on the left of an answer.

Comment: If you cannot change your input data, you need to map the data. Loop over every object and gather all data together into a new object. If you have problems with that, you can open a new question